# My Rails App is not working because passenger is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

In server, I have installed rails,rvm,apache2 and passenger after installation I drag and drop my rails app to the server, It shows [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvD6w.png).

And in apache2/error/log, It shows bundler load error

```
App 9573 stdout:
[ 2017-09-21 09:38:10.4331 9419/7f8c7920d700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/html/vpn_check: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 9c91492c
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-lZdumg.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

I am not sure why im getting this error. Could anyone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Try installing `bundler`

Comment: I installed bundler and the same issue is on. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Paste the output for the following : `gem env`, `which bundler`. Also include your Apache configuration file.

Comment: my ruby version - 2.4.1, rvm version - 1.29.3, rails - 5.1.4, 
`$gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.15.4
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.15.4
Done installing documentation for bundler after 8 seconds
1 gem installed` 

and my bundler version - 1.15.4

Comment: Passenger might be running using a different version of ruby (I'm suspecting that passenger is not running using rvm's ruby but the default system ruby). Looking at `gem env` will help eliminate such assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the rvm ruby version in your apache configuration.
In your case Passenger use ruby version in /usr/lib/ruby, instead of rvm ruby version.

If you just use one rvm gemset, you have to configure ruby version and ruby gemset in Passenger apache module (apache/mods-available/passenger.conf) :

```
PassengerRoot /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-version@gemset/gems/passenger-5.1.2
PassengerDefaultRuby /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-version@gemset/wrappers/ruby
```

If you have multiple application running with different rvm configurations, you have to specify ruby version in vhost files.

Exemple :

```
<Location /appli1>
  PassengerRuby /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1@app1/wrappers/ruby
  RackEnv production
  RackBaseURI /appli1
  Options -MultiViews
</Location>
<Location /appli2>
  PassengerRuby /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2@app2/wrappers/ruby
  RackEnv production
  RackBaseURI /appli2
  Options -MultiViews
</Location>
```

Comment: I have put my path in apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf, but still I get the load error :(

Comment: did you restart apache ? can you show content of  passenger.conf & passenger.load ?

Comment: Yes, I restart my apache and then tried. Anyways, this is my `passenger.conf` file `<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/wrappers/ruby
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
</IfModule>
` and this is my `passenger.load` file `LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so`

Comment: You have two `PassengerDefaultRuby` lines there.

Comment: Anyways, I removed that line and tried once still the same.

Comment: You have to change the path for PassengerRoot too. I edit my first post

Comment: Hey thanks guys, Now it's working. I used this,
`LoadModule passenger_module /home/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/passenger-3.0.0/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/passenger-3.0.0
PassengerRuby /home/[username]/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p0/ruby`

Answer (score 0):

This was not done, So I reinstall the passenger and its dependencies as per its order. Refer this [link](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/install/oss/trusty/) to install passenger and its dependency.

Thank you all for helping me out.